# Setting up Unleash Edge on AWS App Runner

Tags: docker, aws-app-runner, unleash, unleash-edge

I am trying to host a public docker image https://gallery.ecr.aws/unleashorg/unleash-edge#edge on AWS App Runner and I am getting an error on port configuration.

> [AppRunner] Deployment Artifact: [Repo Type: ECR-Public], [Image URL: public.ecr.aws/unleashorg/unleash-edge], [Image Tag: edge]

> [AppRunner] Pulling image public.ecr.aws/unleashorg/unleash-edge from ECR-Public repository.

> [AppRunner] Successfully pulled your application image from ECR.
> [AppRunner] Provisioning instances and deploying image for publicly accessible service.
> [AppRunner] Performing health check on protocol `TCP` [Port: '3063'].
> [AppRunner] Your application stopped or failed to start. See logs for more information.  Container exit code: 2
> [AppRunner] Deployment with ID : 19d4d48e1f284ed29e2d8bbde622415a failed.

Below is the docker cmd that works locally.

`docker run -p 3063:3063 unleashorg/unleash-edge:latest edge`

How should I configure the above docker run cmd in App Runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add a start command in App Runner. Here's my setup:

[Unleash Edge AppRunner start command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAJfa.png)